# Joomla restful web services for user actions

Tags: rest, joomla3.0

Can you please suggest me best way to implement restful web services for user actions, I was looking into Joomla format=json things. I want core Joomla way :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into this service: https://techjoomla.com/rest-api-for-joomla